# Flask-SQLAlchemy db.create_all() raises RuntimeError working outside of application context

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I recently updated Flask-SQLAlchemy, and now `db.create_all` is raising `RuntimeError: working outside of application context`. How do I call `create_all`?

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///project.db'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

db.create_all()
```

This raises the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/david/Projects/flask-sqlalchemy/example.py", line 11, in <module>
    db.create_all()
  File "/home/david/Projects/flask-sqlalchemy/src/flask_sqlalchemy/extension.py", line 751, in create_all
    self._call_for_binds(bind_key, "create_all")
  File "/home/david/Projects/flask-sqlalchemy/src/flask_sqlalchemy/extension.py", line 722, in _call_for_binds
    engine = self.engines[key]
  File "/home/david/Projects/flask-sqlalchemy/src/flask_sqlalchemy/extension.py", line 583, in engines
    app = current_app._get_current_object()  # type: ignore[attr-defined]
  File "/home/david/Projects/flask-sqlalchemy/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 513, in _get_current_object
    raise RuntimeError(unbound_message) from None
RuntimeError: Working outside of application context.

This typically means that you attempted to use functionality that needed
the current application. To solve this, set up an application context
with app.app_context(). See the documentation for more information.
```

Answer (score 76, accepted):

As of Flask-SQLAlchemy 3.0, all access to `db.engine` (and `db.session`) requires an active Flask application context. `db.create_all` uses `db.engine`, so it requires an app context.

```py
with app.app_context():
    db.create_all()
```

When Flask handles requests or runs CLI commands, a context is automatically pushed. You only need to push one manually outside of those situations, such as while setting up the app.

---

Instead of calling `create_all` in your code, you can also call it manually in the shell. Use `flask shell` to start a Python shell that already has an app context and the `db` object imported.

```
$ flask shell
>>> db.create_all()
```

Or push a context manually if using a plain `python` shell.

```
$ python
>>> from project import app, db
>>> app.app_context().push()
>>> db.create_all()
```

Answer (score 8):

Here's an `example.py` that configures a SQLite database, a model, then creates the database. The `with app.app_context()` line around `db.create_all()` is what's needed to avoid the context error.

```py
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = "sqlite:///project.db"
db = SQLAlchemy()

class Article(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String)
    body = db.Column(db.String)

with app.app_context():
    db.create_all()
```

Run the development server with this command, and the database will be created if it doesn't exist.

```
$ flask -A example.py --debug run
```

Answer (score 6):

If you're using a `python` shell instead of `flask shell`, you can push a context manually. `flask shell` will handle that for you.

```
>>> from project import app, db
>>> app.app_context().push()
>>> db.create_all()
```

Learn more about the application context in [the Flask docs](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/appcontext/) or [this video](https://youtu.be/Z4X5Oddhcc8).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a separate script to initialize the database, you can push a context manually.

Do not do this in the application module itself, only in a standalone script. If you push a context globally when setting up the application itself, it will not behave correctly.

```
# init_database.py
from myapp import app, db, Person

app.app_context().push()

db.create_all()
db.session.add_all([Person("A"), Person("B")])
db.session.commit()
```