# ImportError: cannot import name 'db' from 'database_functions'

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm trying to connect to a Postgres database using Flask and SQLAlchemy.
I followed an youtube tutorial however it doesn't seem to work for me, as it throws an error normally associated with circular dependencies.

When i type on the Python console: `from database_functions import db` it says:

`Traceback (most recent call last):   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module> ImportError: cannot import name 'db' from 'database_functions' C:\path\to\file\database_functions.py)`

Here is the code I'm using:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from werkzeug.security import generate_password_hash, check_password_hash
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import serialization
import psycopg2
import configparser
import jwt
from datetime import datetime

if __name__ == '__main__':
    config = configparser.ConfigParser()
    config.read('database.ini')
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = 'postgresql://'+config['postgresql']['user']+':'+config['postgresql']['password']+'@'+config['postgresql']['host']+':'+config['postgresql']['port']+'/'+'survey_platform'
    db = SQLAlchemy(app)

    class SurveyData(db.Model):
        id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
        codigo_do_projeto = db.Column(db.String(250))
```

I expected a database file to be created in the same folder as where I'm running the python command.

Comment: Is this code block you pasted the contents of C:\path\to\file\database_functions.py?

Comment: And do you run the `database_functions.py` file directly? How do you run it?

Comment: Yes, it is the content of the file.
I did not run it, I'm just importing some properties from it through python's console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely a scoping issue. In your file pasted above, the `db` variable is not available at the module level since it's defined inside of an `if` block.

`if __name__ == '__main__':` is typically used when you want a file to be directly executable but not have the executable code at the module level.

For example:

```py
# run.py
print("Hello, World!")
```

versus

```py
# run2.py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Hello, World!")
```

if you run with `python run.py` and `python run2.py` respectively, you'll see identical results. However, if you create another file which imports either of these as modules, you'd see different results - importing from `run2.py` won't print anything but importing `run.py` will.

```py
# another_file.py
import run
# vs
import run2
```

so if you want a file to be used like a module and have other modules import [from] it, objects you want to import need to be at the module level, but you should keep in mind that whatever is at the module level will actually execute on import so if you don't want that to happen, then you should wrap that code into something like `if __name__ == '__main__':`

To clarify, by "module level", I mean not defined inside of any scope-inducing blocks so basically not indented. If you remove your `if` and unindent everything within, you should be able to `from database_functions import db`

Comment: When I try to run db.create_all() this happens:
RuntimeError: Working outside of application context.

This typically means that you attempted to use functionality that needed
the current application. To solve this, set up an application context
with app.app_context(). See the documentation for more information.

Comment: Hmm I don't think so because your `app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"]` is a PostgreSQL string. I'd guess you're copying from a tutorial which uses sqllite(ex. "sqlite:////tmp/test.db"). sqllite is a lightweight sql database which just reads/writes to a local file without a db server. postgresql is different and doesn't just write to 1 nearby file. edit: gonna leave this comment if its helpful even though you deleted the comment this was replying to.

Comment: That is a great answer, I'm a little bit confused but I'm going to get the hang of it.
I tried to db.create_all() rn but it threw the error from the previous comment

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73961938/flask-sqlalchemy-db-create-all-raises-runtimeerror-working-outside-of-applicat for this other issue.

Comment: Sorry for that last question, thanks for the quick reply! I would never have guessed it.